# Showing $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T=UU^T$ given $X=USV^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Given SVD of $X=USV^T$ where $S^T = [\Sigma,  0]$ is full rank, I'm struggling to show that $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T=UU^T$ as stated in the first equation of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133257/243601). My attempt is below:

$$X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$$
$$USV^T(VS^TU^TUSV^T)^{-1}VS^TU^T$$
$$USV^T(VS^TS V^T)^{-1}VS^TU^T$$
$$USV^T(V \Sigma\Sigma V^T)^{-1}VS^TU^T$$
$$US(\Sigma \Sigma)^{-1}S^TU^T$$

I don't know if I've made a mistake somewhere above but if not, I can't figure out how to reduce $S(\Sigma \Sigma)^{-1}S^T$ into $I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked answer, the SVD was most likely taken as an “economic SVD” (a.k.a. “compact SVD”). If $X$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $r$, this means $U$ is an $n\times r$ matrix with $r$ orthonormal columns, $S$ is an $r\times r$ positive diagonal matrix and $V$ is an $r\times r$ orthogonal matrix. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T
&=USV^T(VSU^TUSV^T)^{-1}VSU^T\\
&=USV^T(VSI_rSV^T)^{-1}VSU^T\\
&=USV^T(VS^2V^T)^{-1}VSU^T\\
&=USV^T(VS^{-2}V^T)VSU^T\\
&=UU^T.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $U$ is not necessarily a square matrix, $UU^T$ is in general not equal to $I_n$. That was probably why the author wrote $UU^T$ instead of $I$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not doing the inverse of the product well. Notice that

$$^(^^^)^{−1}^^ =\\ 
U S V^T V^{-T} S^{-1}U^{-1} U^{-T} S^{-T}V^{-1}VS^T U^T
$$

Using this can you solve it? (Use associativity)

**Edit:** I am using the fact that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$.

**Edit 2:** Keep in mind that $U$ is orthogonal as well, so $UU^T = I$.